# Monotorrent: some managers go into Stopping state and never proceed to Stopped

Tags: c#, monotorrent

What exactly is going on?  I've pulled the source into my project in hopes that I could diagnose this but I could use some direction.  My impression is that the stopping state wraps up communication with the tracker and runs checks on the torrent.

I've wired up handlers for TorrentStateChanged and unfortunately it'll never come out of the Stopped state, which means I cannot simply *stop* a torrent manager and move the files.  I've seen a couple discussions on it out on the net but no responses and the project seems a little...stale.  Does anybody have any experience with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally took some time to look for a solution.  If your torrent has trackers that it cannot connect to, MonoTorrent still tries to send an announce that we've stopped the torrent. This isn't a very good idea considering it waits exclusively for a response before completing.

In the constructor for the class `StoppingMode`, change this line:

```
if (manager.TrackerManager.CurrentTracker != null)
```

to this:

```
if (manager.TrackerManager.CurrentTracker != null && manager.TrackerManager.CurrentTracker.Status == TrackerState.Ok)
```